# How do I format/reshape my data to get separate data for each object?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, plotly-python

Currently, my data is in a nested list as [[ID1, Pos1, Time1], [ID2, Pos2, Time2], [ID1, Pos3, Time3]....].

I then put that into a Pandas dataframe. I want to graph position (Pos values) against time for each object ID separately in Plotly, and my searches of plotly documentation haven't helped. What I'd like is for each object ID to have a separate Pos vs Time line plot on the same figure.

How would I do this? I'm unsure whether I should reshape my data first so that repeated ID values are grouped somehow or whether I can do this direct from the plotly plotting function. I'm new at this, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here's the code snippet:

```
dataset=[]
for obj in scene.objects:
    obj_data = [obj.ID, obj.time, obj.pos]
    dataset.append(obj_data)

df = pd.DataFrame(data=dataset, columns=["ID", "Time", "Pos"])
```

Also, the output of the first five entries of the dataframe:

```
    ID  Time  ...  Speed  
0   4   0.0  ...   1.465062   
1   5   0.0  ...   1.195697 
2   6   0.0  ...   1.443732  
3   7   0.0  ...   1.318886   
4   8   0.0  ...   1.258748
```

Comment: Please provide a sample of your dataframe.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by this, the data I gave in the body is the format of the data going into the dataframe. I'll update with a code snippet to try and expand

Comment: Like this: `print(df.head(5).to_dict())`. The output that produces will be enough to re-construct the first 5 rows of your dataframe.

Comment: @richardec I've updated my question. Does this output help? Thank you for taking a look at it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could group the data in your dataframe by "ID" and then add a line plot to the same figure:

```py
import plotly.graph_objs as go


fig = go.Figure()  # Same figure object

for group_name, group_df in df.groupby(["ID"]):
    # group_name is the "ID" value
    # group_df is a dataframe with the rows of each "ID" value
    fig.add_trace(
        go.Scatter(  # This is how we draw a line plot
            x=group_df["Time"], y=group_df["Pos"],
            name=group_name,  # Add the "ID" as the name of the line
        )
    )

fig.show()  # Display figure
```

This is a sample input and expected output using this code:

```
   ID  Pos  Time
0   1    1     1
1   1    3     2
2   0    2     1
3   0    4     2
```

[image: Plot created using Plotly]

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what was needed